# Convert audio in binary into Wav format, Python

Tags: python, librosa

i try to read audio file from Google storage bucket(GCS), but i can read the audio in binary format, it is possible to convert from binary into wav format? since i need to do audio analysis where its read the audio as wav format.
i attached the code how to read audio from GCS in binary format, or any way how to read as wav directly from GCS?

```
import numpy as np
import IPython.display as ipd
import librosa
import soundfile as sf
import io
from google.cloud import storage
import os
import tensorflow.io.gfile as gf

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

os.environ["GCLOUD_PROJECT"] = "fundpro" #project_id
BUCKET = 'parli-2020' #bucket_name
gcs = storage.Client()
bucket = gcs.get_bucket(BUCKET)
import speech_recognition as sr

for blob in bucket.list_blobs(prefix='speech/Transcribe'):
    filename = 'gs://parli-2020/' + blob.name
    with gf.GFile(filename, 'rb') as fp:
        X, sample_rate = librosa.core.load(fp)
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by binary format? WAV technically is a binary format, but I'm assuming your audio is encoded and you're trying to decode it and write it to a wav file?

Comment: credit to @Crash0v3rrid3 for the code to load audio from GCS

Comment: @lnogueir  i think yes,,, i want the audio in wav format, btw tq for your response..

Comment: You need to provide more information about the audio properties. Is it within a container format like mp4? Or is it just pure encoded audio? What's the codec?

Comment: i save the audio in my bucket Google storage in wav format, i have try with multiple way how to load audio from google storage in wav format, but it is possible. and based on suggestion from one person to load the audio as binary.

Comment: Notice that `librosa.core.load` takes a file path. And `fp` is not really a file in your system. You will probably have to do `fp.read()` and then load that to librosa.